# Why doesn't Luke ask about his mother?

Tags: star-wars, luke-skywalker, character-motivation

Luke Skywalker always seems to care heavily about his father, and even after getting to know that Vader is his father, he never seems to ask who his mother was. After all, the stories that his Uncle and Aunt told him, were not really correct, so anything they might (and have) told him should have been questionable to him, too.

Yet, in the movies he never asks about his mother. His father seems to be his only concern. Does he never care who his mother was? After all, it's at least likely that his mom was a Jedi, too. Is there any explanation in the extended universe or maybe even a scene where he does ask?

Comment: As has been stated below, Luke asks Leia briefly in *ROTJ* about their shared mother, and there are at least two occasions in the *Expanded Universe* where he searches for information about her, in *The Black Fleet Crisis* and *The Dark Nest Trilogy*. I would hand-wave the lack of other references to his mother in the original trilogy as simply being influenced by Obi-Wan's claim that Luke's father was murdered. Luke, who already had a healthy father-worship when he thought his dad a mere pilot, may have fixated on Vader at the expense of any thoughts for his mother. A hand-wave, I know.

Comment: Because he didn't speak about his mother, doesn't mean he didn't care. What was he going to say. "I wanna learn how to be a Senator and become like my Mother". Naturaly his dad was more interesting and a hero to him as he knew he fought in the clone wars, further more a Jedi after obiwan told him.

Answer (score 28):

After Luke had learned that Leia is his sister, he asks her if she has any memory of her mother (which Luke now knows is his mother as well):

> **Princess Leia**: Luke, what's wrong?
>
> **Luke**: Leia, do you remember your mother? Your real mother?
>
> **Princess Leia**: Just a little bit. She died when I was very young.
>
> **Luke**: What do you remember?
>
> **Princess Leia**: Just... images really. Feelings.
>
> **Luke**: Tell me.
>
> **Princess Leia**: She was... very beautiful. Kind, but sad. Why are you asking me this?
>
> **Luke**: I have no memory of my mother. I never knew her.

Comment: Obviously this conversation conflicts with the end of Revenge of the Sith, unless Leia had some kind of Force-enhanced super memory. Out-of-Universe, clearly Lucas didn't know yet that 20 years later he would decide to have their mother die at their birth. This conversation has a lot more dramatic impact as-written anyway.

Comment: @EuroMicelli Agreed. That's one of the most obvious SW plot holes.

Comment: @EuroMicelli: I know of some autistic people who claim that hey have memories of their own birth. Putting this, a little bit of force and some "Just images really. Feelings" together makes it not any harder to believe than anything else going on in the star wars universe

Comment: @EuroMicelli this question covers it a little http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11536/how-could-princess-leia-remember-her-real-mother-a-little-bit-when-padmé-am/11546#11546

Comment: I always assumed Leia did not know she was adopted, until Luke told her a couple of minutes later -- so she was talking about memories of her adoptive mother.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit Her adoptive mother was Breha Organa, who died with the destruction of Alderaan, so Leia would have many adult memories of her.

Comment: @ThomasW: OK, but that is never explained in the films.

Comment: Or Leia could have meant Senator Organa's wife?

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit: That Leia was adopted is explained in the novelisation to *Return of the Jedi*, so it was canon before the new trilogy. You're right, it wasn't explained very well in the film.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10931/how-does-leia-have-memories-of-her-mother also explains (in more details than the movies.se question) about Leia's memories

Answer (score 11):

Luke does care about his mother.

In the [*Black Fleet Crisis* trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Fleet_Crisis), Luke goes on a mission to search for his mother which Leia had opposed with the reason that he had already gone over the entire imperial archive as well as force probed Leia multiple times to try to find clues about their mother.

Luke also stumbles across information about his mother in [*The Dark Nest Trilogy*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Dark_Nest_Trilogy), in a hidden segment of R2-D2's memory. This is when Luke finally finds out who his mother really was, after Leia's research determines that the tall blonde man is definitely Anakin Skywalker, and the woman he is speaking with is definitely Senator Amidala of Naboo. This is after Luke begins to suspect that his wife, Mara Jade Skywalker, may have murdered his mother - without knowing her true identity - during her time as Palpatine's servant (known as the [Emperor's Hand](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Emperor%27s_Hand)). These thoughts help prompt the research.

Comment: I was going to post this myself. Well done. You should add that Luke finally discovers who his mother was, and how she died, in *The Dark Nest Trilogy*.

Comment: ah I actually didn't know about that part, haven't gotten there yet. Feel free to edit the answer to give a complete picture.

Comment: Done. Not as good as actual quotes from the books, but I no longer own them. I would NOT recommend bothering with them, by the way. The first book is decent, whereas the other two are tripe. The only redeeming feature of all three is that the Chiss are rightfully shown to be the absolute badasses they should be.