# Did Leia know she was adopted?

Tags: star-wars, princess-leia

At the end of *Revenge Of The Sith*, Leia was adopted by Bail Organa, following the death of her biological mother.
At the end of *Rogue One*, Bail refers to Leia as being his daughter.
During *A New Hope*, Leia is known as "Leia Organa, daughter of Bail Organa".

But did she know she was adopted by the Organa?
Did she know that she's not the biological daugther of Bail Organa?

This could change the vision of the following scene: at the end of *Return of the Jedi*, Leia talks to Luke about her mother, and tells him that she was very beautiful...
Did Leia talk about her birth mother? Or her adoptive mother?

Comment: The linked dupe question makes it very clear that Leia's adoption was public knowledge on Alderaan. I'm intrigued why people think this needs re-opening

Comment: The second half of your question is also a dupe. If you trimmed out the final paragraph and changed the question to "**What does Leia know about the circumstances of her adoption?**", this wouldn't be a dupe (and has a canonical answer)

Comment: IMHO my answer here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10931/how-does-leia-have-memories-of-her-mother/191788#191788  is one of the best possible answers to make based on the movies alone.  I don't read many star wars novels and comics and can't keep track of which are canon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the exact line from the film I'm going to say yes.

From [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10931/how-does-leia-have-memories-of-her-mother) the line was:

> Luke: Leia, do you remember your mother, your real mother?
>
> Leia: Just a little bit. She died when I was very young.

Given the fact that

1. Leia didn't say "what do you mean my *real* mother!?"
2. And she follows up with "She died when I was very young"

I'm going to go with a definite yes

Comment: On the other hand, retcanon would have it that her mother died _before_ Leia was born…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet the best answers we can give are in the linked question or in my answer on Movies: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11536/how-could-princess-leia-remember-her-real-mother-a-little-bit-when-padm%C3%A9-am/11546#11546